# Making a form in community

Tags: community

How to make a form in community so users and enter data and modify existing data that they already put in Salesforce? I mean to say how it this done? Is there anything native or do I need an appexchange app for it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Global actions? Also standard OOB components like **Record Related List**?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways i can think of:

1.You can create a lightning component with the fields you want to expose and show to client

2.You can create a salesforce flow which is configurable with the fields you want and expose that through lightning component.

Lightning data service is another option worth considering by currently i dont think its available for communities.

I saw your other question where you have mentioned about form assembly but i would prefer to stay away from app exchange if all we need to do is simple forms since we have number of ways to do them in salesforce.

Comment: This is helpful RedDevil. Does Option #1 entail coding? Also, can Option #2 allow anyone without a sf user to view Form #1 and then if they are accepted by a moderator at some point, can be asked a security question before they get to Form #2 and only if they are accepted again, can they login to community? If so, how to do this with flows? (in theory, I'd work it out in practice).